# How to match few words with spaces - preg_match()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match only a-z 0-9 and spaces between words and numbers. I try with [a-z0-9\s] but with this regex I match \n \t and \r.

I try with this: http://regexr.com?30rs7 but I don't know is this code work correctly and I ask about the correct regexp :)

Regards,
George!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `[a-z0-9 ]`?

That should do it.

Comment: @T0m3kk: Why shouldn't it be? (Yes it is correct)

Comment: @T0m3kk if you use the ascii space character to match other ascii space characters and don't have any complicated utf8 space characters, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take it literally:

```
[a-z0-9 ]
```

Space instead of `\s` which matches those others you don't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

My regex that i use in your case is this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

Comment: If You match a-zA-Z u can try with [a-z]/i. The flag "i" is ignoreCase :)